# Filling data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas and i have a little data like that.

```
4     1
5     8
6    25
7    33
8    24
9     4
```

and I want to fill in missing parts. I want to like that :

```
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     8
6    25
7    33
8    24
9     4
10    0
```

It's gonna be a list for use. like that [0,0,0,1,8,25,33,24,4,0]
looked for a solution but couldn't find any. Any idea?

Comment: Looks more like a reindexing operation : ``df.set_index(0).reindex(np.arange(11), fill_value = 0).reset_index()``

Comment: Those DataFrames are unclear, is one of those columns the index? are they both columns of data? Do they have headers? Could you update your question to make more clear what the data represents, or, even better, include some executable constructors for the dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
l = s.reindex(range(10+1),fill_value=0).tolist()
```

Comment: i dont want to start with 0. so i add .drop([0, 0]). thank you